# How to remove DataFrame rows where a column's values are in a set?

Tags: python, pandas, set, dataframe

I have a set

```
remove_set
```

I want to remove all rows in a dataframe where a column value is in that set.

```
df = df[df.column_in_set not in remove_set]
```

This gives me the error:

```
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.
```

What is the most pandas/pythonic way to solve this problem? I could iterate through the rows and figure out the the ilocs to exclude, but that seems a little inelegant.

Some sample input and expected output.

Input:

```
 column_in_set value_2 value_3
 1             'a'      3
 2             'b'      4
 3             'c'      5
 4             'd'      6

remove = set([2,4])
```

Output:

```
column_in_set value_2 value_3
1             'a'      3
3             'c'      5
```

Comment: Can you post some example data and expected output?

Comment: I think the usual way to do this is to write `df[~df['column_in_set'].isin(remove)]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To make the selection you can write:

```
df[~df['column_in_set'].isin(remove)]
```

`isin()` simply checks if each value of the column/Series is in a set (or list or other iterable), returning a boolean Series.

In this case, we want to only include rows of the DataFrame which are *not* in `remove` so we invert the boolean values with `~` and use then this to index the DataFrame.